# I'm writing a package. How can make it such that when library(my_package) is called, other packages are loaded as well?

Tags: r

Title should be pretty clear I hope. I'm writing a package called `forecasting`, with imports for `dplyr` among other packages. With the imports written in to the DESCRIPTION file, I am able to force these other packages to be installed along with `forecasting` - is there an equivalent way to do this for the loading of the package? In other words, is there a way that when I load my package with `library(forecasting)`, it automatically also loads `dplyr` and the other packages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Re-read "Writing R Extensions". The `Depends:` forces *both the initial installation as well as the loading* of the depended-upon packages.

But these days you want `Imports:` along with `importFrom()` in the `NAMESPACE` file which is more fine-grained.

But first things first: get it working with Depends.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Opps you're correct, the documentation I referenced is not a primary source.  Perhaps this is better:

From the [R documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies):

> The ‘Depends’ field gives a comma-separated list of package names which this package depends on. Those packages will be attached before the current package when library or require is called.

and

> The ‘Imports’ field lists packages whose namespaces are imported from (as specified in the NAMESPACE file) but which do not need to be attached. Namespaces accessed by the ‘::’ and ‘:::’ operators must be listed here, or in ‘Suggests’ or ‘Enhances’

**Original:**

From the [R packages documentation](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html):

> Adding a package dependency here [the DESCRIPTION file] ensures that it’ll be installed. However, it does not mean that it will be attached along with your package (i.e., library(x)). **The best practice is to explicitly refer to external functions using the syntax package::function()**. This makes it very easy to identify which functions live outside of your package. This is especially useful when you read your code in the future.

Comment: A clarification: that is **not** "the R documentation" which is provided by the authors of R, aka "R Core".